# How can I generate linear elevation raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation

I want to **generate** a raster for testing purposes. I'm using QGIS and I was hoping it would have the tools to do this but I couldn't find a way.

The raster should be 1001 m x 1001 m in size with each point being 1 m x 1 m. The center point should be 500m high and the surrounding points (including the diagonal points) should linearly descent until reaching 0m at the very edge of the pyramid (i.e. 1m descent per point).

This raster should be centered to geographic location 0.0, 0.0 in WGS84 datum.

I'm hoping there's a way to do this in QGIS but other (free) tools are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python script (just paste it into the Python console in QGIS, or run as a .py file there):

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, osr
gdal.UseExceptions()

x = np.arange(0,500,1)
y = np.arange(0,500,1)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
l = np.tril(xx)
u = np.triu(yy,k=1)
m1 = l+ u #lu
m2 = np.rot90(m1,1) #ll
m3 = np.rot90(m1,2) #rl
m4 = np.rot90(m1,3) #ru

h1=np.concatenate((m1,m4), axis=1)
h2=np.concatenate((m2,m3), axis=1)

result = np.concatenate((h1,h2))

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_path = "D:\\raster.tif"
file = driver.Create(output_path, 1000 ,1000 , 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
file.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(result)

# spatial reference goes here
proj = osr.SpatialReference()
proj.ImportFromEPSG(4326)   
file.SetProjection(proj)
file.SetGeoTransform((0.0, 0.005, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.005))

file.FlushCache()
```

Some mathematics should be done. I hope it works.

Comment: This fails at the `file.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(result)` line ("AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'"). Also, could you comment the code to explain how it works?

Comment: @Simbamangu It's strange, because I've laready generated raster with this code, maybe something is wrong with your QGIS Python installation.

Comment: @dmh126 tried it and got the sam error message as Simbamangu

Comment: @Kurt OK I agree, same problem on Windows, but on Linux it works good. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: OK now it should works - just add `gdal.UseExceptions()` and edit `output_path` to path where you have permissions to write files. I've done this on Windows 10 and it works.

Comment: @dmh126  confirmed, now it works!

Comment: This does not do exactly what I asked for but it's close enough, thanks! I added additional answer with the changes I needed to do because the comment section does not allow that many characters.

Comment: I've updated few lines, upper left corner of this raster is in (0.0; 0.0) point, and its resolution is 0.05 horizontal and vertical. If you want to change this, just calculate position you want (check how it works: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html under the Getting Dataset Information)

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by dmh126 is close but not quite what I needed (the center point is not at 0, 0 and the raster is not 1001m x 1001m and the center height is not 500m). I modified his answer a bit and here is what I did:

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

x = np.linspace(0,500,500)
y = np.linspace(0,500,500)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
l = np.tril(xx)
u = np.triu(yy,k=1)
m1 = l+ u #lu
m2 = np.rot90(m1,1) #ll
m3 = np.rot90(m1,2) #rl
m4 = np.rot90(m1,3) #ru

h1=np.concatenate((m1,m4), axis=1)
h2=np.concatenate((m2,m3), axis=1)

result = np.concatenate((h1,h2))

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_path = "C:\\temp\\raster.tif"
file = driver.Create(output_path, 1001 ,1001 , 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
gt = file.GetGeoTransform()
gtl = list(gt)
gtl[0] -= 500.0
gtl[3] -= 500.0
file.SetGeoTransform(tuple(gtl))
file.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(result)
file.FlushCache()
```